# animated passive rigid body not behaving correctly

Tags: animation, modifiers, transforms, rigid-body-simulation, timeline

Deleting bakes did not help me.
[image]

[image]

Blender file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/y82wqv1mwc963gn/movingrigid.blend/file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the *Animated* option of the passive object:

[image]

[image]